# SpringBoot REST Controller test classes PASS separately but FAIL when run together

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, rest-assured

> #### Context:
>
> I have a spring-boot java8 service that takes REST calls and responds with data. I'm writing a custom Authorization Filter that checks the HTTP Header and decides data and decides whether a user is authorized to request data from this service.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebFilter
@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String UNAUTHORIZED_MESSAGE = "AuthorizationFilter : Empty or Invalid Authorization Header";

    ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
       context =  filterConfig.getServletContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if(ValidationUtil.isAuthorized(req)){
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
        } else {
            log.error(UNAUTHORIZED_MESSAGE);
            res.sendError(401, UNAUTHORIZED_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

> I have tests using rest-assured to test that the AuthHeader is set up correctly. This is the basic format of each test class:

```
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(
        classes={Application.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
    )
    public class AuthorizationTest {

        @LocalServerPort
        private int port;

        @Test(timeout=10000)
        public void shouldRespondWithUnauthorizedWhenNoAuthHeader() {
            given().port(port)
                .param("productKeys", PRODUCT_KEY_1)
                .param("productKeys", PRODUCT_KEY_2)
                .get(ITEM_PRICE_ENDPOINT)
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(401);
        }

        @Test(timeout=10000)
        public void shouldRespondWithUnauthorizedWhenAuthHeaderIsIncorrect() {
            Response response = given().port(port)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json"    )
                    .header("Authorization", "anything")
                    .param("productKeys", PRODUCT_KEY_1)
                    .param("productKeys", PRODUCT_KEY_2)
                    .get(ITEM_PRICE_ENDPOINT)
                    .then()
                    .assertThat()
                    .statusCode(401)
                    .extract()
                    .response();

            assertThat(response.<String>path("message")).isEqualTo("You're Unauthorized to view this resource");
        }

        @Test(timeout=10000)
        public void shouldRespondWithDataWhenAuthHeaderFormatIsCorrect() {
            Response response = given().port(port)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", correctAuthHeader)
                    .param("productKeys", PRODUCT_KEY_1)
                    .param("productKeys", PRODUCT_KEY_2)
                    .get(ITEM_PRICE_ENDPOINT)
                    .then()
                    .assertThat()
                    .statusCode(200)
                    .extract()
                    .response();

            assertThat(response.<ArrayList>path("rows")).isNotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

> #### Problem:
>
> *Running the entire suite of tests `gradle clean build` (7 test classes, each w/ 2 or 3 tests) FAILS while running each tests **class** separately PASSES*
>
> I understand that by default spring loads and caches ApplicationContext files so that it doesn't have to reload for every test but I'm not sure how that would effect REST requests. (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-framework)

#### *Any ideas ?*

> #### Tech:
>
> - Java 8
> - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.4.RELEASE
> - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
>
> #### Notes:
>
> *We chose not to use a Spring Security Filter because that level of security will soon be implemented in an API Gateway in front of the service.*

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. Does the test fail with an exception or with assertions? And which assertions fail? Have you tried excluding individual tests to determine which tests conflict?